# Single-word request: something like "inappropriately and embarrassingly public"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a story about a guy who is really fussed about his appearance. I'd like to describe him as having a relationship with his mirror, and I'd like to describe this relationship using a single adjective, or maybe two, if I can make them flow together nicely in the sentence. But I can't think of one that captures what I'm trying to say.

I'm trying to impart that his relationship is unseemly, something that should be kept private but that he makes embarrassingly public, like an inappropriate public display of affection between lovers. I've been all over my thesaurus but can't find a word that really nails it.

Comment: *Image conscious* comes to my mind, perhaps *compulsively image conscious* or *problematically image conscious*.  [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) comes to mind as another possible adjective.  See also [body image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_image).

Comment: Also, +1 on *having a relationship with a mirror*.  I've definitely heard that before and it does well to demonstrate the concept.  (Its only failing being its verbosity, so I'm not saying it is a valid answer given the search for a 1-2 word phrase.)

Comment: If ***narcissistic*** won't do because it only addresses the *guy's* perspective, I suggest [***cringeworthy.***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cringeworthy) But apparently that's peculiarly BrE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's pretty common in American English, too.

Comment: I can't believe nobody has submitted **scandalous**.

Comment: I'm confused which adjective you're looking for.  If you need a word for image conscious, that would be vain as others have suggested.  If you need a word for something 'embarrassingly public', that might be taboo, but it depends.  Does he find his vanity embarrassing, or is he oblivious to it, while everyone else finds it disturbing?

Comment: [*ignominious*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ignominious): deserving or causing public disgrace or shame: [OD]. I think it is usually used with "defeat". *OED* says: "In recent use sometimes in weaker sense, ‘lowering to one's dignity or self-respect’."

Answer (score 10):

> **indecorous**:
>       adjective in·de·co·rous (ˌ)in-ˈde-k(ə-)rəs; ˌin-di-ˈkȯr-əs\
>   Definition of INDECOROUS
>
> :  not decorous :  conflicting with accepted standards of good conduct
>   or good taste — in·de·co·rous·ly adverb — in·de·co·rous·ness noun

[merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indecorous)

His indecorous relationship with his mirror publicly displayed his vanity.

Answer (score 9):

[Vain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vain) and [*vainglorious*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vain&searchmode=none) come to mind:

> adjective
>
> Having or showing an excessively high opinion of one’s appearance,
> abilities, or worth:
>
> ODO

In the same way that it is acceptable to enjoy intimacy with your spouse, it is generally acceptable to think highly of your appearance or abilities, as long as you don't make a public spectacle of it.

This meaning of vain is likely from [*vainglorious*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vain&searchmode=none):

> vain (adj)
>
> c.1300, "devoid of real value, idle, unprofitable," from Old French
> vain, vein "worthless, void, invalid, feeble; conceited" (12c.), from
> Latin vanus "empty, void," figuratively "idle, fruitless," from PIE
> *wa-no-, from root *eue- "to leave, abandon, give out" (cognates: Old English wanian "to lessen," wan "deficient;" Old Norse vanta "to
> lack;" Latin vacare "to be empty," vastus "empty, waste;" Avestan va-
> "lack," Persian vang "empty, poor;" Sanskrit una- "deficient,"
> Armenian unain "empty").
>
> Meaning "conceited, elated with a high opinion of oneself" first
> recorded 1690s in English; earlier "silly, idle, foolish" (late 14c.).
> Phrase in vain "to no effect" (c.1300, after Latin in vanum) preserves
> the original sense. Related: Vainly; vainness. Compare also
> vainglory.
>
> vainglorious (adj.)
>
> early 15c., from *vainglory* + -ous, or from Old French vain glorios
> "boastful, swaggering." Related: Vaingloriously; vaingloriousness.
> Groce ("Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue," 3rd ed., 1796) has
> vain-glorious man "One who boasts without reason, or, as the canters
> say, pisses more than he drinks."
>
> vainglory (n):
>
> c.1200, "worthless glory, undue pomp or show," waynglori,
> from Old French vaine glorie, from Medieval Latin vana gloria (see vain + glory
> (n.)).
>
> etymonline.org

Answer (score 7):

**Indiscreet** seems to fit:

> not having or showing good judgment : revealing things that should not be revealed ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indiscreet))

Answer (score 4):

After discarding "narcissistic," I thought "exhibitionist(ic)" might do. "Unseemly" comes to mind too. Ooh, and thesaurus.com gives "blatherskite" as a synonym for exhibitionist.

Comment: What's wrong with *narcissistic*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Narcissistic" only deals with his own vanity, and not the public inappropriateness.

Comment: And [blatherskite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blatherskite?s=t) has nothing to do with being a "show off". (not my downvote)

Comment: A single word is difficult! "Tawdry" now comes to mind, seeing meretricious.

Comment: Glad to hear @Mari-LouA

Answer (score 3):

You could always try

> **meretricious**
>   *adj*
>   Attracting attention in a vulgar manner: *meretricious ornamentation*

It comes from the Latin for prostitute, so it definitely hits the "embarrassingly public" drum, and points to some kind of vulgar spectacle.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as far as a one word adjective, you have been provided plenty, but I think a complete sentence for what you are trying to convey could be:

"His self-absorbed relationship with his mirror is a direct reflection of his own vanity."

Get it?  Reflection and vanity?  A double double entendre?  Is that a thing?

Answer (score 1):

> What about-
>
> Imprudent - lacking discretion, wisdom, or good judgment
>   (**[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imprudent)**)

Answer (score 1):

Why an adjective; why not a verb

> His eyes *caressed* his own image in the mirror
>
> He *made love* to his image in the mirror
>
> He *ogled* himself in the mirror

If you need an adjective, again consider those of sexual attraction

> He cast *seductive (licenscious/lurid/lustful)* looks upon himself in the mirror

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, deferring the presence of the mirror until after the build up?

> With a gentle knock, she entered his office.
>   His eyes took in the striking figure - well-dressed, oozing
>   sensuality, quite a catch by anyone's standards, with hair that you just
>   longed to run your fingers through. With a sigh, he reluctantly turned
>   from his mirror and contemplated his guest.

Answer (score 1):

I see that *narcissistic* has been mentioned once or twice, but not really offered as an answer.  However, since the question allows a (short) phrase, I'd like to suggest that his behavior was **flamboyantly narcissistic**.  Alternatively, you could call him a **flaming narcissist**.